# React Native - 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1

I recently upgraded an older project from RN 0.63.2 to RN 0.71.2 after which I run into the following issue when trying to build the project:

`'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found`

I found two ways to fix the error:

1. Use `arch -x86_64 pod install` instead of `pod install`
2. Run XCode (14.2) using Rosetta

Both seems not ideal. I can run a new RN project just fine with `pod install` and non-Rosetta XCode.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, are you using M1 chip? I am using old architecture, it still has this issue and no idea how to fix, these solutions does not work for me

Comment: I'm also having this issue on an Intel Mac. Any ideas?